# Redirect (rewrite?) all .PDF requests on Apache server to .php file

Tags: php, apache, pdf, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I am building an application that necessitates redirecting (or is it rewriting? I need to do the one where the URL remains the same on the client side) to a .php file for all requests that occur for .pdf files in a given directory on my web server (Apache). However, I only want this request to be rewritten if the user is trying to display the PDF in a browser (not download it). I have a feeling this second part is not possible.

Does anyone have some good resources to look into that not only depict the syntax that I will need to use but also what is going on behind the scenes with the Apache server?

Also, does anyone have an idea as to how I can determine if the file is being directly downloaded or requested via web-browser? I have a feeling that, since when you access a PDF file via a browser, it seems to download it and display it using the Adobe Reader plugin, that there is no distinction that can be made between the two.

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On

   # only if not an actual file exist
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   # only if not an actual directory exist
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule /your-directory/path/(.+)\.pdf $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

1. It is rewriting.

2. There is no distinction between viewing and downloading. If a request is received by your Apache server, it will give a response. The response will be whatever your PHP script will output. Update: @corretge has given you an answer related to this. I think it's not entirely reliable to rely on headers sent by the client, but you can try that solution.

3. Here you can learn about [Apache's mode_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: If OP copy your code exactly, he will have server error. Comments cannot start in the middle of the line. The whole line is treated as comment if **first** non-whitespace character is `#`. In all other situations it will be treated as part of directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#syntax

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks! Placed them there for explanation, but forgot to tell the OP to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but you can also try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$  /downloadPdf.php?pdf=$1.pdf [L,NC,QSA]
```

And in the /downloadPdf.php script query for HTTP headers with headers_list() if any of these are present:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
```

If download headers are present, send the file with

```
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . stripslashes($this->ubqDoc[$this->camp]['name']) . "\"");
```

And the force download headers.

Else, send the file with this header

```
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" . stripslashes($this->ubqDoc[$this->camp]['name']));
```

You need to manage other headers, like Content-Type and Content-Lenght

Read the [fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) PHP manual about send files from PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your input. While the information here is definitely useful the other answer more directly answers my questions.

Comment: Don't worry, but I'm curious : You recive differents header if PDF is force-download or if is showed in the browser?

Comment: I have not tested to confirm as of yet, but according to the above response the headers are slightly different. I'll do some network sniffing and post the answer here.